# data.table R || sum specific column from list of data tables

Tags: r, data.table, reduce

```
library(data.table)    
dt_store<-list()
A <- data.table(a = paste0("gid",1:4), b = paste0("IID",12:15),value=seq(from=1, to=4))
B <-  data.table(a = paste0("gid",1:4), b = paste0("IID",12:15),value=seq(from=11, to=14))
C <-  data.table(a = paste0("gid",1:4), b = paste0("IID",12:15),value=seq(from=21, to=24))


dt_store[[1]]<-A
dt_store[[2]]<-B
dt_store[[3]]<-C
```

I'd like to sum/add column `value`. Each data.table in the list has same number of rows and same column names. The column `b` is unique. There can be duplicates in column `a`

I would like to get the final output as:

```
    a     b final_sum
 gid1 IID12  33
 gid2 IID13  36
 gid3 IID14  39
 gid4 IID15  42
```

`Reduce("+",lapply(dt_store,value))` #this errors out.

How do I use `Reduce` or `lapply`, `mapply`? I can use a for loop but that would be naive. Sorry as these key functions are difficult to hang of to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` to rbind the `list` elements and then do a group by `sum`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(dt_store)[, .(final_sum = sum(value)), .(a, b)]
```

-output

```
#       a     b final_sum
#1: gid1 IID12        33
#2: gid2 IID13        36
#3: gid3 IID14        39
#4: gid4 IID15        42
```